# Amazon MWS API: - _POST_PRODUCT_DATA_ SubmitFeed gives error

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-mws

I am trying to submit a new product feed for the the Beauty / HairCareProduct product.

Here is the xml request I am trying to submit.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
    <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>xxxxxxxx</MerchantIdentifier>
      </Header>
      <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
      <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
      <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
            <SKU>BU07612251AC</SKU>
            <Condition>
                <ConditionType>New</ConditionType>
            </Condition>
            <DescriptionData>
                <Title>Coconut Oil Baobab Sulfate-Free Invigorating Shampoo</Title>
                <Brand>ORS</Brand>
                <Description>Lather-rich, sulfate-free shampoo gently cleanses while reparative oils and plant-derived protein nourish and help reinforce strands to invigorate and revive damaged hair and dry scalp</Description>
            </DescriptionData>
            <ProductData>
                <Beauty>
                    <ProductType>
                        <HairCareProduct>
                            <Directions>The product is applied on wet hair and massage into lather. Rinse well. ‭Repeat, if necessary, leaving on hair 2 to 3 minutes. Rinse thoroughly. ‭Follow with HAIRepair Restoring Conditioner. </Directions>
                        </HairCareProduct>
                    </ProductType>
                </Beauty>
            </ProductData>
        </Product>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

When I submit this request and check the result, I can see the error as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>xxxxxxxxxx</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>ProcessingReport</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <ProcessingReport>
            <DocumentTransactionID>xxxxxxx</DocumentTransactionID>
            <StatusCode>Complete</StatusCode>
            <ProcessingSummary>
                <MessagesProcessed>1</MessagesProcessed>
                <MessagesSuccessful>0</MessagesSuccessful>
                <MessagesWithError>2</MessagesWithError>
                <MessagesWithWarning>0</MessagesWithWarning>
            </ProcessingSummary>
            <Result>
                <MessageID>0</MessageID>
                <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
                <ResultMessageCode>90215</ResultMessageCode>
                <ResultDescription>100% of the products in your file did not process successfully. We recommend using Check My File to help you identify and correct common listing errors before updating your inventory. To use Check My File, upload your file on the "Add Products via Upload" page in the "Check My File" section.</ResultDescription>
            </Result>
            <Result>
                <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
                <ResultMessageCode>99001</ResultMessageCode>
                <ResultDescription>A value is required for the "part_number" field.</ResultDescription>
                <AdditionalInfo>
                    <SKU>BU07612251AC</SKU>
                </AdditionalInfo>
            </Result>
        </ProcessingReport>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Please not, my category of product is Beauty / Haircare product.
Let me know what's wrong in in xml file. I have tried lots of tutorials, examples to solve this, but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

The error message refers to `part_number` which is the name of a CSV column (called "flat files" in MWS). In XML you need to specify a `StandardProductID` instead, like this:

```
        <StandardProductID>
            <Type>EAN</Type>
            <Value>1234567890123</Value>
        </StandardProductID>
```

Please also note, that my `Beauty.xsd` does not have `HairCareProduct`. I had to change this to `BeautyMisc` to validate the feed - but that may be due to an outdated set of XSDs.

Answer (score 0):

I see this as the error from Amazon:

> A value is required for the "part_number" field

They want data for that field.  Can you supply it?

Is there anything here that might help?
https://forum.nitrosell.com/t/multiple-errors-when-trying-to-upload-items-to-amazon/674/10

Comment: Can you please post a valid xml example request for a product belong to the Beauty/Haricare category ?I created the above request by refering the Beauty.XSD, but no luck.